# Batch size for panel data for LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, panel-data

I have repeated measurements on subjects, which I have structured as input to an LSTM model in Keras as follows:

```
batch_size = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, time_steps, features), return_sequences=True))
```

Where time_steps are the number of measurements on each subject, and features the number of available features on each measurement. Each row of the data is one subject.

My question is regarding the batch size with this type of data.
Should I only use a batch size of 1, or can the batch size be more than 1 subjects?

Related to that, would I benefit from setting stateful to True? Meaning that learning from one batch would inform the other batches too. Correct me if my understanding about this is not right too.

Answer (score 2):

Great question! Using a batch size greater than 1 is possible with this sort of data and setup, provided that your rows are individual experiments on subjects and that your observations for each subject are ordered sequentially through time (e.g. Monday comes before Tuesday). Make sure that your observations between train and test are not split randomly and that your observations are ordered sequentially by subject in each, and you can apply batch processing. Because of this, set shuffle to false if using Keras as Keras shuffles observations in batches by default.

In regards to setting stateful to true: with a stateful model, all the states are propagated to the next batch. This means that the state of the sample located at index i, Xi will be used in the computation of the sample Xi+bs in the next batch. In the case of time series, this generally makes sense. If you believe that a subject measurement Si infleunces the state of the next subject measurement Si+1, then try setting stateful to true. It may be worth exploring setting stateful to false as well to explore and better understand if a previous observation in time infleunces the following observation for a particular subject.

Hope this helps!